# Change component's content according to the url in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular2-routing

I have one component where I want to show data according to the one of the categories.
categories - [sport, cars, fashion, politics].

In my NewsCategoriesComponent I need to show changed data when I'm clicking on the nav buttons.

How can I change data of component after clicking on nav buttons?

here is my routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'category', component: NewsCategoriesComponent},
  {path: '**', component: DashboardComponent}
];
```

Comment: Most likely through a `Resolver` which reads up the `ActivatedRoute` and loads data, based on the given `category`.

Comment: Please add the code for showing an item in a component

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the category as a parameter in your route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'category/:category', component: NewsCategoriesComponent},
  {path: '**', component: DashboardComponent}
];
```

Then read the parameter from the route in the NewsCategoriesComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news-categories',
  templateUrl: './news-categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news-categories.component.css']
})

export class NewsCategoriesComponent {
  category: string;

  constructor(private actRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.category = this.actRoute.snapshot.params.category;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's showing right content only once after clicking on nav buttons it's not changing.

Comment: I need to see the code for your component to be able to pinpoint the problem.